# After yum update openldap not workin

Tags: linux, centos, openldap

In my network squit proxy server authenticates open ldap members and allows internet connection at 192.168.1.254:3128. Openldap server on another machine 192.168.1.2(centos).After "yum update" ldap not working fully.

```
slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d
```

config file testing succeeded

On *.1.2 machine installed phpldapadmin. before "yum update " I logined normally. After yum update phpldap admin not logining. It throws 
`This base cannot be created with PLA.`

On Ldap server :

```
ldappasswd -xWD cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com -S uid=sferuz,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
New password:
Re-enter new password:
Re-enter new password:
Enter LDAP Password:    
Result: No such object (32)
```

Please, help me.

Comment: in addition  ` ldapsearch -D "cn=Manager,dc=seismos,dc=uz" -W`
`Enter LDAP Password:`
`# extended LDIF`
`#`
`# LDAPv3`
`# base <dc=seismos,dc=uz> (default) with scope subtree`
`# filter: (objectclass=*)`
`# requesting: ALL`
`#`

`# search result`
`search: 2`
`result: 32 No such object`
``
`# numResponses: 1`
`

Answer (score 0):

OpenLDAP has changed the way is configured, until "now" the changes were made in the slpad.conf file. Now, it uses dynamic configuration that allows you to make changes in the server without restarting it. If you want to migrate your configuration, you should check this guide: [OpenLDAP using OLC](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/slapd-config.html)